# can we more than one id/class to text box,

Tags: asp.net

Can i give more than one id/class in below asp text box

```
<asp:TextBox ID="test" runat="server" CssClass="textbox" Style="width: 125px;"
                                        MaxLength="12">
                                    </asp:TextBox>
```

Comment: You can give multiple class but single id

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? And why do you lump together ID's and classes? The question is not clear in it's current state.

Answer (score 3):

You can give more than one css class `CssClass="textbox editable wide"`, but id no. Id should be unique.